Figure description centering under graph in LaTeX
I am trying to properly center the Figure caption under these graphs but I really don't know how I should do it. Technically the figure itself starts about where you have the A_405 but I want the figure caption centered below the "Time [min]" Since the way it is right now just looks very wrong. Any idea what I can do about this? The package I use for the graphs is pgfplots.
This is my code for the graphs:
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \definecolor{customblue}{HTML}{1f77b4}
        \definecolor{customred}{HTML}{d62728}
        \definecolor{customgreen}{HTML}{2ca02c}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={Time [min]},
            ylabel={A\textsubscript{405}},
            grid=major,
            thick,
            ymin=-0.05, ymax=0.7,
            domain=0:6,
            legend style={at={(0.02,0.98)}, anchor=north west, draw=none, fill=none, nodes={anchor=west}},
        ]
            % 0h
            \addplot[
                dotted,
                thick,
                color=customblue,
                mark=*,
                mark options={solid}
            ] coordinates {
                (0,0.024) (1.1,0.019) (2.167,0.015) (3.333,0.018) (4.417,0.020) (5.433,0.024)
            };

            % 2h
            \addplot[
                dotted,
                thick,
                color=customred,
                mark=*,
                mark options={solid}
            ] coordinates {
                (0.000, 0.072) (1.083, 0.109) (3.200, 0.222) (4.283, 0.286) (5.317, 0.351)
            };

            % Eluate
            \addplot[
                dotted,
                thick,
                color=customgreen,
                mark=*,
                mark options={solid}
            ] coordinates {
                (0.000, 0.085) (0.783, 0.144) (2.050, 0.261) (2.967, 0.385) (4.050, 0.508) (5.067, 0.627)
            };

            % Legend
            \legend{
            \hspace*{2pt} 0h,
            \hspace*{2pt} 2h,
            \hspace*{2pt} Eluate
            }
            
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Absorption Spectroscopy of the wild ru1 protein}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{0.03\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \definecolor{customblue}{HTML}{1f77b4}
        \definecolor{customred}{HTML}{d62728}
        \definecolor{customgreen}{HTML}{2ca02c}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={Time [min]},
            ylabel={A\textsubscript{405}},
            grid=major,
            thick,
            ymin=-0.021, ymax=0.3,
            domain=0:6,
            legend style={at={(0.02,0.98)}, anchor=north west, draw=none, fill=none, nodes={anchor=west}},
        ]
            % 0h
            \addplot[
                dotted,
                thick,
                color=customblue,
                mark=*,
                mark options={solid}
            ] coordinates {
             (1.067, 0.001) (2.100, 0.006) (3.100, 0.005) (4.100, 0.007) (5.167, 0.008)
            };

            % 2h
            \addplot[
                dotted,
                thick,
                color=customred,
                mark=*,
                mark options={solid}
            ] coordinates {
             (1.000, 0.022) (2.083, 0.021) (3.100, 0.021) (4.117, 0.020) (5.133, 0.022)
            };

            % Eluate
            \addplot[
                dotted,
                thick,
                color=customgreen,
                mark=*,
                mark options={solid}
            ] coordinates {
             (1.083, 0.008) (2.100, 0.082) (3.100, 0.125) (4.150, 0.176) (5.367, 0.228)
            };

            % Legend
            \legend{
            \hspace*{2pt} 0h,
            \hspace*{2pt} 2h,
            \hspace*{2pt} Eluate
            }
            
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Absorption Spectroscopy of the mutated ru1 protein}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}



Please add a suitable preamble. I guess you get some Overfull hbox message.

Your code cannot be reproduced, making hard test the code and find solutions, but I suggest you place a \fbox{} around each minipage to check where are really the plots with  respect the minipage areas. Probably you will see that the captions are well placed and that the true issue is the plot size and position.
